# Installing CoqIDE - Update of jhbuild failed

Tags: coq, coqide

I have Coq already installed, now I am trying to install CoqIDE on Mac. I am following the [Coq wiki](https://github.com/coq/coq/wiki/Installation-of-Coq-on-Mac). The build fails at the second step. When I run

> sh gtk-osx-build-setup.sh

This is the error I get:

```
Checking out jhbuild (<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk-osx/raw/master//jhbuild-revision">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) Server at git.gnome.org Port 443</address>
</body></html>) from git...
Already on 'master'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
error: branch 'stable' not found.
Already up-to-date.
fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'stable' at the same time.
Update of jhbuild failed
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you tried [coq-8.8.0-installer-macos.dmg](https://github.com/coq/coq/releases/download/V8.8.0/coq-8.8.0-installer-macos.dmg)? You can get the full list of releases here: https://github.com/coq/coq/releases

Comment: This works. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can find binary distributions on [Coq's GitHub](https://github.com/coq/coq/releases/).

At the time of writing [coq-8.8.0-installer-macos.dmg](https://github.com/coq/coq/releases/download/V8.8.0/coq-8.8.0-installer-macos.dmg) seems to work.